# Selecting Conversation From Database Based on Recipient

Tags: php, sql

I have been working on a PHP messaging system and I would like to implement two methods of accessing a particular conversation/thread.

The first one is querying the ID of the conversation (`message/{numeric ID}`), which is pretty simple and straightforward. It is also the only way to query for a group message.

The section method is querying for a personal '1-on-1' message thread (`message/{alphanumeric user ID}`). I will lay out the three tables used below.

Table `conversations`:

```
id | locked | timestamp
```

`timestamp` denotes the time of the last message in the conversation for the sake of having less queries when sorting.

Table `participants`:

```
id | conversation | member | timestamp
```

`conversation` is foreign ID key from `conversations`, `member` is the foreign key for table `members` and `timestamp` is the last activity of the user in the conversation for 'seen' functionality purposes.

Table `messages`:

```
id | member | conversation | message | timestamp
```

The columns are pretty self-explanatory here.

Now, I would like to fetch the ID of the conversation where I only have the person A and person B as participants based on their member ID's.

I have thought about this for hours and no elegant solution comes to mind.

Comment: Only A and B. So there should be no other persons, correct?

Comment: Indeed, that's correct - only A and B, no one else.

Comment: But the result could be more than one conversation with these criteria. Do you want all or only the latest?

Comment: It could be more than one, certainly. For example if a conversation has person A, B and C, then another person A, B and D. That would mean I would have all three conversations as the result, but I would like to make it so that it disregards the results where there is a third party involved, yet maintaining optimal queries. I could certainly accomplish it by selecting all relevant threads and checking each for member count, thus disregarding those with 3+ participants, but I am convinced there has to be a more sophisticated solution.

Comment: Yes thats all true but it may exist more than one conversation with A and B only! Or shouldn't it? And yes i think the only way is to select those with sum of participants=2 only.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear in the description. Conversations are unique to the participants in them. You cannot create multiple conversations with the same participants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c.id, c.timestamp
FROM conversations c
RIGHT JOIN participants p_a ON (p_a.conversation=c.id)
RIGHT JOIN participants p_b ON (p_b.conversation=c.id)
WHERE 
  p_a.member='A-ID' AND 
  p_b.member='B-ID' 
GROUP BY c.id 
HAVING count(*)=1 
ORDER BY c.timestamp DESC
```

Took 0,012 sec +network on 1M records in participants and 400K records in conversations.

`conversations.id` is a **PK**, `participants.conversation` is a **FK** linked with `conversations.id`, `participants.member` is a **KEY** and `conversations.timestamp` is a **KEY**.

Comment: Why max c.timestamp if you group by c.id? There can be only one timestamp for this group.

Comment: Excellent and elegant. Very much appreciated.